# Batch file to move file(s) to new location

Tags: batch-file

just need a simple batch file to move different files to a new location. Want it to do a cut and paste job. Don't want to have to specify a particular source file or location, just want to drop the file on the .bat and have it moved to the new location.

Thanks!

Comment: And what is your specific question? Please read at least the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to use this site!

Answer (score 0):

To move a file in batch call this command:

```
move "old_path" "new_path"
```

To overwrite files at the new path call `move` with a `/Y` switch:

```
move "old_path" "new_path" /Y
```